# Powershell gettting parent directory doesn't work with ordinary files when listed by `dir`

Tags: powershell

The following doesn't work:

```bsh
function WTF {
  foreach ($Path in $(dir)) {
    echo $(Get-Item $Path).parent
  }
}
```

If the current directory contains subdirectories, then their parents will be printed, but it doesn't work on ordinary files. Why not?

Comment: Try `.Directory`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens, as Get-ChildItem returns an array of objects. The catch is that an array in Powershell can contain objects of different types. Get-ChildItem will populate the array with `FileInfo` objects for files, and `DirectoryInfo` objects for directories.

The [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netcore-3.1) class doesn't have `.Parent` member, but [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netcore-3.1) does. Thus the disparity in the results.

If one tries to use a strongly typed array, it won't end up well:

```
[IO.FileInfo[]]$ff = gci
Cannot convert the "SampleDirectory" value of type
  "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" to type "System.IO.FileInfo".
At line:1 char:1
+ [IO.FileInfo[]]$ff = gci
```

Assuming you have a directory with files and subdirectories, it's easy to check what'll gci will return. In my test directory, the first entry is a directory and the last is a file. The results for calling `.GetType()` are like so,

```
$ff=gci
$ff[0].gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name            BaseType
-------- -------- ----            --------
True     True     DirectoryInfo   System.IO.FileSystemInfo


$ff[-1].gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name            BaseType
-------- -------- ----            --------
True     True     FileInfo        System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Comment: But I'm using `Get-Item` (`gi`) though? I mean, if I use `gi` together with a string path to a file, it works: `$(gi "C:\SomeDirectory\SomeFile.txt").parent` works and prints out `C:\SomeDirectory` as expected. So why doesn't my code work? In my code, I've even tried `(gi "$Path").parent`, which still doesn't work.

Comment: @Ray Are you sure `SomeFile.txt` isn't a directory? `$(gi "C:\Windows\notepad.exe").parent` errors as expected: `The property 'parent' cannot be found on this object.` whilst `$(gi "C:\Windows").parent` works.

Comment: Oh sorry I lied! It doesn't work. It autocompletes in the Powershell terminal so I assumed it would work. When I tried it it didn't work LOL.